# How do I make a form modal in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to create a child form that helps the user to enter data for a field in the parent form. I want this child form to be modal, but what do I need to do to make this form modal?

Is there's a different type of item I need to use?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use [`Form.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

As Bob mentioned, you should set [`Form.DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) accordingly on your modal form.

Comment: Don't forget about setting DialogResult on the Buttons of said Form

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without blocking?  I'd like to make the dialog modal, but I still want to send information to it in my code...but I can't if it's blocking.

Comment: @NielW you should post a question about that

Answer (score 24):

Use the `ShowDialog()` method instead of `Show()` when you display the child form.

Answer (score 20):

```
Form f = new Form();
f.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: What's `this` doing there? Why is been used?

Answer (score 10):

Call the **ShowDialog** method.

```
Form f = new Form();
f.ShowDialog(this);
```

For more info click this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 6):

After you close the modal form, dispose the resources

```
using (Form form = new Form())
{
  form.ShowDialog(this);
} // Dispose form
```

The `using` statement ensures that `Dispose` is called even if an exception occurs within the `using` block.

More [using statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)