# Get hold of a window which pops up in an in-built function

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop

Having inched slightly closer to this question-

[Fixing a prompt window over the main window in a windows application using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235668/fixing-a-prompt-window-over-the-main-window-in-a-windows-application-using-c-sha/41235787?noredirect=1#comment69672535_41235787)

I am asking this question in a hope that I will be able to fix the above. Here's it. How do get hold of a pop-up window that is thrown from an in-built function in C#.

The method is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document.CheckSpelling() and the pop-up window is the Spell-Check dialog box.

Comment: What do you mean with "get hold of"? Obtaining a hwnd?

Comment: Yes. The nearest solution I have gotten so far with this is in using [DllImport("User32.dll")].

Comment: How about this? :-)

Answer (score 0):

This example finds the spell checker window and closes it.

1) Find process of Word

2) Enumerate all windows belonging to this process ID

3) Get the window with the appropriate class name

4) Close that window

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Word = NetOffice.WordApi;

namespace WordSpellCheckerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var app = new Word.Application())
            {
                SpellCheckerDemo(app);
            }
        }

        private static async void SpellCheckerDemo(Word.Application app)
        {
            app.Visible = true;

            var doc = app.Documents.Add();

            doc.Words.First.InsertBefore("Here's some text that requiires speell cheking");

            var process = GetProcess(app);

            var task = new Task(() => CheckSpellingTask(doc));
            task.Start();
            //Wait for the window to open
            Thread.Sleep(4000);

            //I found the classname by comparing the list of windows for the process before and after opening the spell checker
            //Then I checked the title to confirm
            var spellCheckerWindow = WindowStuff.GetWindowsWithPID(process.Id).FirstOrDefault(w => w.ClassName == "bosa_sdm_msword");

            //Do something with the window
            spellCheckerWindow.Close();

            //Wait for the task to finish before closing
            task.Wait();

            doc.Close(false);
            app.Quit();
        }

        private static async Task CheckSpellingTask(Word.Document doc)
        {
            try
            {
                doc.CheckSpelling();
            }
            catch { }
        }

        //From my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673726/get-specific-window-handle-using-office-interop/41462638#41462638
        private static Process GetProcess(Word.Application app)
        {
            var tempDocument = app.Documents.Add();
            var project = tempDocument.VBProject;
            var component = project.VBComponents.Add(NetOffice.VBIDEApi.Enums.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
            var codeModule = component.CodeModule;
            codeModule.AddFromString("#If Win64 Then\r\n   Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib \"kernel32\" () As Long\r\n#Else\r\n   Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib \"kernel32\" () As Long\r\n#End If");

            var result = app.Run("GetCurrentProcessId");

            var process = Process.GetProcessById((int)result);

            tempDocument.Close(false);

            return process;
        }

        //Hacked together from the pInvoke pages for these WinAPI calls
        public class WindowStuff
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, [Out] StringBuilder lParam);
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            private static extern bool EnumWindows(WindowEnumerator lpEnumFunc, ArrayList lParam);

            private delegate bool WindowEnumerator(IntPtr handleWindow, ArrayList handles);

            const uint WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
            const uint WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
            const uint WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;

            public struct Info
            {
                public uint Hwnd;
                public uint PID;
                public string ClassName;
                public string Title;

                public Info(IntPtr hwnd )
                {
                    uint processID;
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processID);

                    Hwnd = (uint)hwnd;
                    PID = processID;
                    ClassName = GetClassName(hwnd);
                    Title = GetWindowTitle(hwnd);
                }

                public void Close()
                {
                    SendMessage(new IntPtr(Hwnd), WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                }
            }    

            public static List<Info> GetWindowsWithPID(int pID)
            {
                return GetWindowsInner().Cast<IntPtr>().Select(hwnd => new Info(hwnd)).Where(i => i.PID == (uint)pID).ToList();
            }

            private static ArrayList GetWindowsInner()
            {
                var windowHandles = new ArrayList();
                WindowEnumerator callBackPtr = GetWindowHandle;
                EnumWindows(callBackPtr, windowHandles);
                return windowHandles;
            }

            static string GetWindowTitle(IntPtr hwnd)
            {
                int length = (int)SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Capacity, sb);
                return sb.ToString();
            }

            private static bool GetWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle, ArrayList windowHandles)
            {
                windowHandles.Add(windowHandle);
                return true;
            }

            private static string GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd)
            {
                var className = new StringBuilder(256);
                return GetClassName(hWnd, className, className.Capacity) != 0 ? className.ToString() : string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```