# Trying to use another form's function but not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable my form when another opened, and enabled when closed. But another forms may close itselves and open new forms so I wite a function which gets boolean value and enables and disables forms and keys. When opening new for it works but when closed that form not working.

Here is main form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Automation_v1_0_0
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        bool keysActivated = true;

        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void anotherForm(bool anotherform)
        {
            if (anotherform)
            {
                this.Enabled = false;
                keysActivated = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Enabled = true;
                keysActivated = true;
            }
        }

        private void FormMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (keysActivated)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F7)
                {
                    FormSettings settings = new FormSettings();
                    anotherForm(true); // Enters and working.
                    settings .Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my settings form:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Automation_v1_0_0
{
    public partial class FormAyarlarMenu : Form
    {
        public FormSettings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void FormSettings_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape || e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
            {
                FormMain fm = new FormMain();
                fm.anotherForm(false); // Enters but not working.
                this.Close();
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: You made a new FormMain which is not an already existing one.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is open the `setting` form as a modal if that is correct then you can use `settings.ShowDialog()` which will disable any click on the parent caller and will open the child form as a modal. for more reference go check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2503090/2417602)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem. Here is my code:

```
namespace Automation_v1_0_0
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {    
        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F7)
            {
                FormSettings settings = new FormSettings();
                 settings.ShowDialog();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will work, but it would be better to dispose the settings form after use. The easiest way to do that is to put the creation of the settings form inside a `Using()`construct

Comment: Also I dont think you still need the `keysActivated`variable

Comment: I hope you will do it like in my answer, because this code has a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

you are making this complex while it can be simple

in your mainform do this :

```
    private void FormMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F7)
        {
            using (FormSettings settings = new FormSettings())
            {
              settings.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
```

and just drop all other code you dont need that.
Drop the method anotherform, you dont need that.

in your settings form just do this

```
private void FormSettings_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape || e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main form:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    bool keysActivated = true;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FormMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (keysActivated)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F7)
            {
                this.Hide();
                FormSettings settings = new FormSettings(this);
                settings.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting form:

```
public partial class FormSettings : Form
{
    private FormMain formMain;

    public FormSettings(FormMain formMain)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.formMain = formMain;
    }

    private void FormSettings_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape || e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
        {
            this.Close();
            formMain.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Your problem is that you instantiated new `FormMain` object instead of using existing one! The solution is that you pass the current instance of `FormMain` to setting form to use it.

Comment: Why do you create a new instance of FormMain in FormSettings ?

Comment: Sorry, typographical mistake from copy&paste! edited. Thanks @GuidoG