# Disable form if another form is active

Tags: c#

I have a form1 for registration and form2 that popups for another inputs. How can I disable going to form1 if the form2 is still opened? Or if items on form1 is being clicked, the form2 will popup telling that users need to finish inputs on form2. And how can I prevent the form2 from going to the background if it is not yet closed.

Thank you

Comment: What you are asking is called: modal Dialog/window.

Comment: Set Form1 Enabled to false then show Form2

Comment: Yeah sorry i didn't know the term 'modal' so I had a hard time finding the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Form.ShowDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog) / [`Window.ShowDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog) instead of `Show` method:

```cs
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Using `ShowDialog` method will not allow any activity out of `Form2`.

Comment: Already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2503079/692942).